# Insert data/keys in redis DB so that memory is in GB

Tags: python, redis, scripting

We have framework which uses Redis DB but the overall flow of the architecture does not insert much data in redis. We want to stress test the redis-DB to a point so that used_memory_human: is > 2 GB

```
#Memory
used_memory:697112016
used_memory_human:664.82M
used_memory_rss:732340224
used_memory_peak:716741496
used_memory_peak_human:683.54M
used_memory_lua:36864
mem_fragmentation_ratio:1.05
mem_allocator:tcmalloc-2.2
```

I looked online but not found a straight forward solution.

Please can someone help here to insert more data in it using a script or other in build commands. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

A simple for loop in any language can be used to generate synthetic data. Alternatively, you can call `DEBUG POPULATE n` (where n is the number of keys to create).

An example that works on my laptop - play with n to get other results:

```
127.0.0.1:6379> INFO memory
# Memory
used_memory:1081264
used_memory_human:1.03M
...

127.0.0.1:6379> DEBUG POPULATE 10000000
OK
(9.32s)
127.0.0.1:6379> INFO memory
# Memory
used_memory:1079299264
used_memory_human:1.01G
```

Comment: Please can you provide an example

Comment: An example of what?

Comment: How to populate random keys to redis-server using python or how to use DEBUG POPULATE n?